# Woocomerce notices keep remaining on page instead of updating and removing old notices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, divi

My issue is that I'm using Divi which doesn't have an add to cart button feature but you can add one by putting this bit of code into functions.php :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
```

Now, I have a mini cart set up in the cart page which allows users to shop for more things to get free shipping. When they click the Add to Cart button implemented with the code above, the cart refreshes to add it. However, the previous woocomerce notifications don't dissapear - new ones just get posted below it.

Example:

User is in their cart -they see a notification at the top saying:

" You'll receive 500 points when you checkout."

User then adds something from minicart into their main cart.

Instead of the woocomerce notice updating, they now have two notifications:

" You'll receive 500 points when you checkout."

" You'll receive 550 points when you checkout."

Now before someone tells me to do something with wc_clear_notices();

I already have this bit of code which works when someone clicks on the update cart button:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 'clear_notices_on_cart_update', 10, 1 );

function clear_notices_on_cart_update() { 
        wc_clear_notices(); 
    };
```

But it only works when the update cart button is clicked. How do I default this so when the user clicks on "Add to Cart" from the minicart displayed on the cart page - It will update the notifications instead of displaying the duplicate each time? Or each time the cart updates in any manner - it removes the old woocomerce notices?

Edit:
Added an example of how the notices are set up on my site. This one for example is an anchor notice on mobile that when u click the button, takes you to the minicart at the bottom.

The other notices are set up the same way but with different functionality. Regardless of what's in the function - they all repeat when Add to Cart is clicked.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'mobile_notice' );
 
function mobile_notice() {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() != 0 && wp_is_mobile()) {
        $notice = sprintf('Add *3 of these exclusive products to the cart for $19.99 and get <strong>FREE SHIPPING!</strong><br><a href="#mobiletext" style="" class="button wc-forward">Get Free Shipping</a>');
        wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
    } 
 
}
```

Here's an image of the notices if it helps any.
[Notice Duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFJxK.png)

Comment: Could you publish the entire code in which you place the notices?

Comment: Hey @VincenzoDiGaetano edited the original post. Can't really post all the code as it would be a violation in terms of privacy for my company however all the notices on our site follows the same syntax as the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `wc_clear_notices();` before adding the new notice:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'mobile_notice' );
function mobile_notice() {
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() != 0 && wp_is_mobile()) {
        wc_clear_notices();
        $notice = sprintf('Add *3 of these exclusive products to the cart for $19.99 and get <strong>FREE SHIPPING!</strong><br><a href="#mobiletext" style="" class="button wc-forward">Get Free Shipping</a>');
        wc_print_notice( $notice, 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. I've attached a picture of the error that might be helpful - it's what it looks like on mobile if a customer added something to cart - the woo notices keep duplicating each time.

Comment: I'm sorry but then I don't know how to help you. Did you clear the cache? Have you tried changing the priority of the `clear_notices_on_cart_update function`? If nothing works try to contact the theme support, they will surely know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Appreciate you trying to help!